# AJAX request makes subsequent requests slow

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, jqxhr

I have a link, which when clicked performs an AJAX request, which completes in 1-2 seconds

when that request completes, it calls itself again, but this time it sends the page a timestamp (which it has received from the previous AJAX request)... The php page takes the timestamp, and checks to see if a certain file is newer than the timestamp sent... this loops... as soon as it is true, data is sent back and the request gets called again with the new timestamp

This keeps repeating

Now, if someone clicked on the link in the first place, which begins this "cycle", and then navigates elsewhere, the new page to which the person navigated to ALWAYS takes between 20-30 seconds to load!!!

On the Chrome Developer Tools Network Console, I can see that the AJAX call that had last been made gets cancelled, and then the new requested page shows up below it and says pending... then about 20-30 seconds later, the page loads, and the status changes to OK with the time shown (between 20 - 30 seconds)

I can't figure this out, it's so freustrating..

P.S. I have read: [Canceled AJAX request slows subsequent navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373278/canceled-ajax-request-slows-subsequent-navigation) This sounds like my problem, but the answer isn't helpful (at least to me)

Comment: What web server are you using?  A single-threaded web server like wsgiref could cause this problem if the server is tied up still finishing the AJAX call before serving the new request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394271/separated-php-process-stop-all-site/17394314#17394314

Comment: @chris Thanks, that helped :) I just passed in the userID using AJAX rather than getting it using SESSION. Then i removed the the unnecessary session_start(), and everything worked properly :)

Hey, could you post your reply as an answer please. Just in case someone else reads this question... thanks :D